# how to avoid an exception in cpp?

Tags: c++

I am writing a code and I know I have an exception in it, but I am sure that my program will not fall in that exception but visual studio is not letting me compile my code is it a way around it?

I tried try catch but it is not working, I am not sure how to use noexecpt and ether it can be used here or not.

```
void func(auto value, bool loc)
{   
    bool chk == loc;
    if(chk == 1)
    {
        int ans = value;
    }
    else
    {
        string ret = value;
    }
}
```

I want to select where the value go depends on its type
for -> chk = 1 it is an int
for -> chk = 2 it is an string

Comment: That's a type error, not an exception.

Comment: Does this code even compile? (Auto as argument?)

Comment: Dont think this is C, do not tag unrelated language.

Comment: How can `chk` become 2?

Comment: @Galik im using cpp

Comment: @JVApen im using templates in my actual code so thats compile this is just an idea what i want to do

Comment: @JVApen chk can be 0

Comment: Agreed, though in your explanation you say: 1 or 2

Comment: Why don't you use function overloading?

Comment: I am practicing templates I was wondering if I can sort variables depending on there type

Comment: There is nothing in the question or its code example that even hints at templates. You need to fix your question to ask what you really want, or close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I honestly don't see the point you try to go to, I suspect you simply need function overloading:

```
void func(int value)
{
// Some code working with int   
}

void func(string value)
{
// Some code working with string
}

void f()
 {
     func(42); // calls the first variant
     func(string{}); // calls the second variant
 }
```

No need to pass an extra argument to indicate what the type is